Incomplete item serialization
We have a JSS project which is hosted on Vercel. The usual workflow is that we make our changes on the dev instance, switch to UAT, pull, make a new branch, updated the serialized items by deleting the items in folders /src/items/feature,foundation,project, use the dotnet sitecore ser pull -n dev and then push to GitHub using the provided command.
Our issue is that not all items get serialized, sometimes even less than 50% of our changes are added to UAT. We miss stuff like GraphQL query updates on renderings, and security access rights on content items.
Is this because we are not using the dotnet sitecore ser push -n uat command also, or are we missing something?
Thank you

I have been trying to figure out how to answer this, whether to close or just comment. I believe that while this is very much on the edge of a question that could be closed due to clarity, I want to add this to hopefully clear up what appears to be a lot of confusion.
Your description of your usual dev workflow does not follow a standard practice. I will outline a basic process here and I hope that you can apply these principles to fix your workflow.

The usual workflow is that we make our changes on the dev instance,

This is a good practice when you are building against a cloud instance (XM Cloud), for XP or XM on premises or PaaS this would normally be done on a local developer instance vs a shared instance.

switch to UAT, pull, make a new branch,

This is where your flow doesn't make sense to me. The next step should be to run dotnet sitecore ser pull, you can use the -n dev to explicitly pull from the dev environment if you are working on a cloud instance. I'm not sure why you would be switching to your UAT instance.

updated the serialized items by deleting the items in folders /src/items/feature,foundation,project, use the dotnet sitecore ser pull -n dev and then push to GitHub using the provided command.

Again, this doesn't make a lot of sense, you shouldn't have to delete anything. Just pulling the items from dev and committing those changes to source control should be enough.
As to why they are not being deployed to your UAT instance will very much depend on how you CI/CD process is deploying your items.

Sorry about the lack of clarity, I don't know if it will help move this forward but I will try to address everything you mentioned.
We are indeed using XM Cloud.
These steps haven't been dictated by me, as I am not TL, we are following a hand-over procedure so I'll take it one step at a time.
I suppose we're pulling from UAT to have everything updated (which is indeed a bit redundant considering we're not SUPPOSED to make changes there, but I think this rule's been broken at times).
Deleting those items.., the changes should overwrite the old files so.. yea.
Thank you for your answer

I meant the same for deleting those items, which seems redundant, since they should be overwritten. I couldn't add everything because of the character limit.
